# How to change base address in WF4.0 Workflow Service?

Tags: wcf, configuration, workflow-foundation-4

There's a Workflow Service Library exposed as WFC Service. I'm trying to change its base address via web.config file. I've succeded in changing relative address of the endpoints, but I need to change base address too. How can I do this?

Here's my config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviors">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:777/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMyService" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>    
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceBehaviors">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <mexHttpBinding>
      </mexHttpBinding>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your hosting in Visual Studio you may need to edit the properties of your WCF Service project.

In Solution Explorer

- navigate to your WCF Service project
- right-click and choose Properties
- select the Web tab
- in the Servers section choose Specific Port and change the Virtual Path and/or port

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are using a web.config I am assuming that you are hosting this inside if IIS right?

If so IIS is responsible for the base address. You create your virtual folders there and they, combined with the machine name, form the base address. All you can specify in the web.config is the final relative bit.

Comment: Right now I'm hosting it in Visual Studio. I'm going to use windows service when deploying to production.

Answer (score 0):

There're several examples of manual configuration of the endpoints [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=35ec8682-d5fd-4bc3-a51a-d8ad115a8792&displaylang=en)
 (Microsoft samples for WF & WCF 4.0). Check for these ones:

- WF\Basic\Execution\ManagementEndpoint\
- WF\Basic\Execution\CreationEndpoint\
- WF\Basic\Execution\ResumeBookmarkEndpoint